# Keycloak 18 add login theme translation

Tags: keycloak, keycloak-18

I was able to create my own `Keycloak 18.0.2` login theme called `custom`. Now, I'd like to add Ukrainian translation for the login screen. I created the following file:

```
/keycloak/themes/custom/login/messages/messages_uk.properties
```

but unable to find `uk` locale in Keycloak admin console.

What am I doing wrong and how do I correctly add new translation properties for the Keycloak login theme?

Comment: Did you add the locale to `theme.properties`?
Keycloak docs: [Adding a language to a realm](https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/server_development/#adding-a-language-to-a-realm)

Comment: yes, in my custom theme I have only `login` folder. I added `../custom/login/messages/messages_uk.properties`  file. Also, added `locales=en,uk` to the  `../custom/login/theme.properties`. And still unable to select uk locale

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have the same problem. The **uk** tag is not visible.

Just type **uk**, press Enter and Save changes.

Also add this:

```
locale_uk=\u0423\u043a\u0440\u0430\u0457\u043d\u0441\u044c\u043a\u0430
```

to *login/messages/messages_en.properties* file.

After all this changes the Ukrainian language will be available on login form.

---

Another way to fix this - add **'uk'** to this array:

```
var supportedLocales = ['uk'];
```

in file
<your_theme>/admin/resources/js/controllers/realm.js:549

Comment: Thank you very much! Do you have a translated messages_uk.properties file?

Comment: Yes, I've added messages_uk.properties file.

Comment: Thank you! I apologize, but I'm unable to see this file. Where was it added?

Comment: No, I have not added any files here (stackoverflow).

Do you need a messages_uk.properties file with Ukrainian translations?

Comment: Yes, I'll really appreciate if you could provide to me translated messages_uk.properties files with Ukrainian translations

Comment: Yes, no problem. But some text is not fully translated.
Here you can find a file https://gist.github.com/NikolayYakovenko/51ef13db0560f07561f393f594360353

Please notice that some Ukrainian words with an apostrophe, like ім''я or зв''яжіться are written using double apostrophe.